# How do you get absolute values and square roots

Tags: java, math

How do you get a square root and an absolute value in Java?

Here is what I have:

```
if (variable < 0) {
    variable = variable + variable2;
}
```

But is there an easier way to get the absolute value in Java?

```
variable = |variable|
```

Comment: Is there actually a programming language that defines |x| as abs(x)?

Comment: @CookieOfFortune Time to go make another programming language...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the static methods in the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class for both - there are no operators for this in the language:

```
double root = Math.sqrt(value);
double absolute = Math.abs(value);
```

(Likewise there's no operator for raising a value to a particular power - use `Math.pow` for that.)

If you use these a lot, you might want to use *static imports* to make your code more readable:

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

...

double x = sqrt(abs(x) + abs(y));
```

instead of

```
double x = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class, and specifically for absolute value and square root:, the [`abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) and [`sqrt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) methods.

Comment: The [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Math.abs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28double%29):

```
variableAbs = Math.abs(variable);
```

For square root use:

```
variableSqRt = Math.sqrt(variable);
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the square root equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.sqrt(Math.abs(variable))
```

Couldn't be more simple can it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class my{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
    double a,b,c=0,d;
    d=1;
    d=d/10;
    int e,z=0;
    System.out.print("Enter no:");
    a=x.nextInt();

    for(b=1;b<=a/2;b++)
    {
        if(b*b==a)
        {
            c=b;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(b*b>a)
            break;
        }
    } 
    b--;
    if(c==0)
    {
       for(e=1;e<=15;e++)
        {
            while(b*b<=a && z==0)
            {
                if(b*b==a){c=b;z=1;}
                else
                {
                    b=b+d;          //*d==0.1 first time*//
                    if(b*b>=a){z=1;b=b-d;}
                }
            }
            d=d/10;
            z=0;
        }
        c=b;
    }

        System.out.println("Squre root="+c);





}    
}
```

Comment: This program is return absolute value of square root,I create this code in java language

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentNum = 5;
double sqrRoot = 0.0;
int sqrRootInt = 0;



sqrRoot=Math.sqrt(currentNum);
sqrRootInt= (int)sqrRoot;
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary to this answer to explain how it solves the OP? It probably won't be obvious to everyone why your solution answers the question.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt replied only for square root of a number